# MySQL INSERT multiple rows with same WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am currently able to insert rows into a table using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 11),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 7))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 12),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 7))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 19),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 9))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 27),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 10))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 45),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 10))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 51),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 10))
INSERT INTO ots (score_id,tab_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM score WHERE score_id = 52),(SELECT tab_id FROM tab WHERE layover_state = 11))
```

The above `INSERT INTO` statements work correctly. However, they seem very inefficient since there should be some way to do this with lists that capture all the integers I need to specify as part of the nested `SELECT` statements. However, I am not sure how to put `score_id` into a SQL list while also preserving the order of `layover_state` in a separate list.

**Question**

Is there a way to replace the above lines of code with one line that uses 2 SQL lists for the numbers?

**Additional Information:**

I am using MySQL with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: A row in score and the a row in tab_id are related is some way or not?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366814/insert-multiple-rows-using-select

Comment: Yes, as @Reversal suggests, an INSERT SELECT would let you do this with one query.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the INSERT SELECT approach. To me it seems like it is just a repeat of the approach that I already used. It just seems like it uses a UNION whereas I have used a comma to separate the SELECT statements. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It would be nice if you can answer @scaisEdge question. What is the relation between `score` and `tab`? I.e.: how do you know `score_id = 11` is related to `layover_state = 7`? Answering this question will clarify what's the best solution for your issue.

Comment: Sure. For each score, there can be one or multiple tabs. In the SQL lines I posted in the OP, only one tab is assigned for each score.

Comment: Yet no answer. I would like to know how are related to each other the elements of the couples `(score_id,layover_state)`. What I am asking you is how you know that `score_id = 11` is related to `layover_state = 7`, how `score_id = 12` is related to `layover_state = 7` and so on.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I missed that. Those `layover_state` values are just labels and each `score_id` has a particular label. A user assigns the `label` to each `score_id` some unrelated knowledge of the scores. Hope that helps.